# How to limit swap usage without using sysctl or resizing the partition?

Tags: kernel, fstab, swap, ram, zram

There is the following scenario: I have an HDD disk that uses LVM and I cannot resize the partitions in it, in this disk, there is a swap partition that is 10gb. I also use zram apart from disk based swap, so I cannot tweak sysctl parameters because I am using these values to make zram work well. Also, the swap disk has -1 priority while the zram is top priority, nevertheless, the swap disk usage is way higher than it should be, so I thought resizing it to 1gb would avoid this.

The only option that I thought about was setting up fstab to pretend the swap is smaller than it is, but as I researched, could not found a way to configure it.

The information about the disk is the following:

```bash
┌──(rootdebian)-[~skid]
└─# pvdisplay -m
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt
  VG Name               debian-vg
  PV Size               <930.52 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238212
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          238212
  PV UUID               3SCpEr-CHMe-96gN-mN9y-goNs-3ZOj-Mk4JcD
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 2383:
    Logical volume  /dev/debian-vg/swap
    Logical extents 0 to 2383
  Physical extent 2384 to 238211:
    Logical volume  /dev/debian-vg/root
    Logical extents 0 to 235827
```

Comment: LLVM or LVM (Logical Volume Manager)? And what is the map of disk and VG?

Comment: LVM (I mistyped), I have updated the question with more information, let me know if this is enough or I need to run any more commands

Comment: Do you have free space on harddisk? Do you have critical apps on this server (can you stop the swap)?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with swap usage? Why do you care?

Comment: Because swap on disk is slow, and the system swaps way more than it's supposed to